# How to add the diagnostic settings to the azure service using .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-data-factory

How the diagnostic settings can be added and configured to the Azure Data Factory from an asp.net core web app using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use azure management sdk.

**1.Install the following nuget package:**

[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent, version 1.33.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/).

[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent, version 1.33.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent/).

**2.Create credentials:**

If you have [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) installed locally, or you can use [azure cli from azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) directly. Then follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication#mgmt-auth) to create credentials. In short, type the following azure cli command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth
```

Then you get the `clientId`, `clientSecret`, `tenantId` from the output, please save these values. The output like below:

[image]

**3.Then use the code below:**

```
        string clientId = "xxx";
        string clientSecret = "xxx";
        string tenantId = "xxx";

        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                    .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                                          clientSecret,
                                          tenantId,
                                          AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

        azure.DiagnosticSettings
            .Define("test2")
            //the resource id of your ADF
            .WithResource("subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/your_ADF_name")
            //the resource id of your azure log analytics
            .WithLogAnalytics("subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/your_azure_log_analytics_name")
            .WithLog("ActivityRuns", 7)
            .WithLog("PipelineRuns", 7)
            .WithMetric("AllMetrics", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 0)
            .Create();
```

Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/eventhub-dotnet-manage-event-hub-events/blob/master/Program.cs#L85) from github.

And you can also you azure monitor rest api [Diagnostic Settings - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnosticsettings/createorupdate) to setup it.